# The inequality $|X+Y| \succ |X| + |Y|$ can never hold for matrices (?)

Tags: matrices, operator-theory

I know that the absolute value of a (self adjoint) matrix does not satisfy the triangle inequality. That is, if we denote for a (self adjoint) matrix $X$ by $|X|$ its absolute value, equal to $\sqrt{X^{*} X}$ then there exist matrices $X$, $Y$ so that $|X| + |Y| - |X+Y|$ is not positive semidefinite ( as an example, one can take $X$, $Y$ non-commuting projectors of rank $1$). However, it seems plausible that the opposite inequality $|X+Y| \succ |X| + |Y|$ can never hold. It may just be a one-line argument.

Answer (score 1):

For the  trace of $|X|$ ( which is the sum of singular values of $X$) we have:

$$\operatorname{trace}|X| = \sup \sum_{i=1}^m \langle T e_i, f_i \rangle$$ over all possible unitary bases $(e_i)$, $(f_i)$, so from here we get 
$$\operatorname{trace}|X+Y| \le \operatorname{trace}|X| + \operatorname{trace}|Y|$$